# Issues with larger context lengths in a transformer model like GPT

Tags: transformer, attention, gpt, computational-complexity

Based on my understanding, one of the issues with longer context lengths is the computational complexity of attention mechanism which is quadratic. But is this really a problem on modern hardware with parallel CPU's?

Eg: 32k context length (GPT4) has a complexity of O(32k * 32k) which is O(1024 million).

Are there any other issues apart from the above which are impeding transformer models from supporting larger context lengths?

As a side note, even if larger context lengths leads to slower non-interactive responses, I think it can still be very helpful in a lot of scenarios